# How to add proxy with auth to undetected-chromedriver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I have to use undetected-chromedriver for some websites, but I also need to add a proxy with authentication. The usual ways that work with regular chromedriver don't work with undetected-chromedriver. Here's what I have tried:

1:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
seleniumwire_options = {'proxy': {'https': 'type://username:pass@host:port'}}
driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True, seleniumwire_options=seleniumwire_options)
```

2:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

options = uc.ChromeOptions
options.add_argument("--proxy-server=https://username:pass@host:port")
driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True, options=options)
```

Are there other ways that work with undetected-chromedriver?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best method I have found.

```
import os
import shutil
import tempfile

import undetected_chromedriver as webdriver


class ProxyExtension:
    manifest_json = """
    {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "manifest_version": 2,
        "name": "Chrome Proxy",
        "permissions": [
            "proxy",
            "tabs",
            "unlimitedStorage",
            "storage",
            "<all_urls>",
            "webRequest",
            "webRequestBlocking"
        ],
        "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},
        "minimum_chrome_version": "76.0.0"
    }
    """

    background_js = """
    var config = {
        mode: "fixed_servers",
        rules: {
            singleProxy: {
                scheme: "http",
                host: "%s",
                port: %d
            },
            bypassList: ["localhost"]
        }
    };

    chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});

    function callbackFn(details) {
        return {
            authCredentials: {
                username: "%s",
                password: "%s"
            }
        };
    }

    chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
        callbackFn,
        { urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
        ['blocking']
    );
    """

    def __init__(self, host, port, user, password):
        self._dir = os.path.normpath(tempfile.mkdtemp())

        manifest_file = os.path.join(self._dir, "manifest.json")
        with open(manifest_file, mode="w") as f:
            f.write(self.manifest_json)

        background_js = self.background_js % (host, port, user, password)
        background_file = os.path.join(self._dir, "background.js")
        with open(background_file, mode="w") as f:
            f.write(background_js)

    @property
    def directory(self):
        return self._dir

    def __del__(self):
        shutil.rmtree(self._dir)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    proxy = ("64.32.16.8", 8080, "username", "password")  # your proxy with auth, this one is obviously fake
    proxy_extension = ProxyExtension(*proxy)

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument(f"--load-extension={proxy_extension.directory}")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    driver.get("Just a moment...")
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

[SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) has a special undetected-chromedriver mode that lets you set the proxy settings via method arg (or on the command-line).

`pip install seleniumbase`, then run with `python` after you fill in the proxy settings on Line 3:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True, pls="none", proxy="USER:PASS@HOST:PORT") as sb:
    sb.open("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
    sb.assert_text("OH YEAH, you passed!", "h1")
    sb.post_message("Selenium wasn't detected!")
```

It sets `uc` to True (to enabled undetected-chromedriver mode), it sets `pls` to "none" (a different pageLoadStrategy might freeze up proxy tests in that mode), and it sets the `proxy` settings (after you fill in the one you want).